# Porting Linux project to windows platform with VS2015 using “mussel" library

Tags: windows, static-libraries

I could find that vs2015 comes with mussel library which is more like to use POSIX calls. I went through the installation guide provided and through the official [link](http://www.musl-libc.org/), came to know that I need to run configuration file followed by make.
  But the configuration file has not been provided with vs2015.
I request you to let me know the procedure if someone has done this before.

Comment: AFAIK musl is Linux-only.

Comment: As it comes as VS2015 along with third party license I thought there should be a way to get it done. The folder location is <i>Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcpackages\IntelliSense\iOS\OSS\musl-1.1.10</i>

Comment: That seems stuff used when targeting iOS, not Win32. In particular, it seems to be there just so that IntelliSense knows how to complete code targeting iOS.

Comment: By folder structure, Yes.Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'll make it a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

musl doesn't support Windows; [from the FAQ page](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html):

> ## What are musl’s dependencies?
>
> - Linux 2.6 or later. Earlier versions will suffice for running most simple single-threaded programs, but due to bugs and conformance issues at the kernel level, musl is not offically supported on earlier kernels.

(now, Windows 10 does support running Linux binaries through WSL, but in that case you would be building musl through gcc inside the Linux "container" and it would be another kind of game entirely)

> As it comes as VS2015 along with third party license I thought there should be a way to get it done. The folder location is *Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcpackages\IntelliSense\iOS\OSS\musl-1.1.10*

As said in the comment, from the folder name it seems that it's there just to aid IntelliSense when editing code for iOS targets.